# How should I approach testing functions that call already deployed contracts? [ethers.js] [chai] [mocha]

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, testing, mocha, test

Suppose my contract utilizes the WETH contract (address 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2) in some manner.

I can write test cases with Chai/Mocha just fine for most cases (they're "deployed" in memory, not needing any gas), but the limitation to that is I can't get access to any contracts/data on the actual Ethereum blockchain.

Is there any for me to get such data locally? Or would I have to essentially copy the WETH contract and deploy it within the test suite to test with it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a mainnet fork for testing. You can interact with the Ethereum mainnet contracts locally without impacting the actual chain nor deploy them manually.

Read more:

- [Mainnet fork with Hardhat](https://mixbytes.io/blog/how-fork-mainnet-testing)
- [Mainnet fork with Ganache](https://www.quicknode.com/guides/web3-sdks/how-to-fork-ethereum-blockchain-with-ganache)